# Full password protected website

Tags: php, html, passwords

Good day!
I'm trying to make a website where you could only access it by first typing the password in the front page(www.mywebsite.com/index.php)

Once I enter the password, It will get the file home.html from outside my public_html.

Then in that page(home.html) there will be links using the variable z (www.mywebsite.com/index.php?z=one) which will return 1.html or other pages.

Here's what I tried so far, but even if i use www.mywebsite.com/index.php?z=one
it still opens home.html
Can I get some help? And/or is what I'm trying possible?

```
<?php
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
if ($pass == "1234") {
    $page = $_GET['z'];
    if ($page == "one") {

        include("../1.html");
    } else {
        include("../home.html");
    }
} else {
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <form role="form" method="POST" style="margin: 0px" action="index.php">
                <input type="password" name ="pass" class="form-control" id="pwd">  </input>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Enter"></input>
            </form>
        </html>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Good code indentation aids in readability but more importantly in Debugging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats not the way to approach this.

First make use of a session, but only hold a `isLoggedIn` flag in the session not the password.

Second, all scripts can be in the `public_html` folder, but what you do is add a little script that checks the loggedIn state to all scripts and if not loggedIn throw the login page

Heres a simple example

login_check.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ( ! isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) || $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == 0) {
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit;
    }
```

Now in your login script

login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ( isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'] && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == 1) {
        // already logged in
        header('Location: index.php.php');  // or some other page
        exit;
    }

    If ( "The password is correct" ) {   // this is of course pseudo code
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = 1;
        header('Location: somepage.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Now in **all your other scripts**

```
<?php
    // first thing is always to check if this user is logged in
    // so any access from a user not yet logged in just get
    // thrown to the login page, or maybe your index.php
    require_once 'login_check.php';
```

You can also use this session to hold useful but not sensitive things like

```
$_SESSION['user_id'];   // id of the users info in user table
$_SESSION['FirstName'];
$_SESSION['LastName'];
$_SESSION['nickname'];
```

and anything else that might be useful to know across your application that you dont want to go to the database each time to collect.

#### Additional info

Your HTML is not well formed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form role="form" method="POST" style="margin: 0px" action="index.php">
   <input type="password" name ="pass" class="form-control" id="pwd" />  
   <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-danger" value="Login" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well, but after i click Enter/submit the password. It doesn't detect yet that I'm logged in so I need to refresh the page or log in again. Any way to fix that?

Comment: Yea I amended the `login.php` page. So now you get sent to some other page on a successful login attempt.

Comment: Is there a way for the session=1 to stay only for few minutes then return back to session=0? or auto logout using this?

Comment: The session only has a limited lifetime. The time it will stay in existance after its last access is set in the PHP.INI file by this parameter `session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440` in seconds [See the manual for session handling](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: In login.php, third line
`if ( isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'] && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == 1) {`
has unbalanced parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the get/post pass in a session like $_SESSION['pass']
But you better encrypt it with a sha1 a least like

```
$_SESSION['pass'] = sha1($pass);
```

and to get it back

```
if($_SESSION['pass'] == sha1("1234")){}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).

But it is not a good practice to store your password in a session.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['pass'])){
    $_SESSION['p'] = md5($_POST['pass']);
    //$pass = $_POST['pass'];
    if($_SESSION['p'] == md5("1234"))
    {
        $page = $_GET['z'];
        if($page == "one")
            {
            include("../1.html");
            }
        else
            {
            include("../home.html");
            }

    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this will help you.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!empty($_POST['pass']) && $_POST['pass'] == "1234") {
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
}


if (empty($_SESSION['pass'])) {
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <form role="form" method="POST" style="margin: 0px" action="index.php">
            <input type="password" name ="pass" class="form-control" id="pwd">  </input>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Enter"></input>
        </form>
    </html>
    <?php
    die;
}

$page = $_GET['z'];
if ($page == "one") {

    include("../1.html");
} else {
    include("../home.html");
}
?>
```